# Can dimensions be skipped in queries against R/R*/X-Trees?

Tags: geospatial, spatial, multidimensional-array, spatial-query, r-tree

Let's say we have a 4 dimensional tree with dimensions longitude, latitude, altitude and for illustration purposes, price.

Can we query against longitude and latitude and optionally against either altitude and/or price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, obviously you can do that. For window queries, just ignore the dimensions or query with an infinite rectangle in that dimension. For range or knn, use a distance function that skips these dimensions.

However, for range/kNN queries, a distance function using both latitude/longitude and e.g. price is nontirival to define. Euclidean distance obviously is not very sensible, as $1 is not the same "distance" as 1 degree in latitude.

The R*-Trees in ELKI should support this out of the box AFAICT. If you query the tree with a projected distance, it will use only these attributes.

Comment: I spent a lot of time in Google and read many articles, and not one covered this :). I would query distance only on lat-long, and range on the other two.

Comment: That should work. Naively, it can be seen as using a distance of infinity for rectangles/points that do not overlap the range you specified, and euclidean distance in latitude and longitude otherwise as on approximation of physical distance (unless you are too far from the poles or include alaska - then you really should look into the great circle distance)

Comment: I am going to heavily modify the data going into the r-tree, and use multiple r-tree (distributed), so I won't have the usual problems. Thanks for your help.